# Make google image search initiate on press of 'enter'

Tags: javascript, image, search, search-engine, enter

http://protected-river-1861.herokuapp.com/ Link to my site

So, I need to let the search of Google Images initiate on the press of the 'enter' key. Currently, it only works on the click of the button.

HTML:

```
<p>Enter the keyword to search for images</p>
<input id="search-term" type="text">
<button id="go-search">Go!</button>
<div id="search-results"></div>
<div style="width: 150px; margin:0 auto;">
```

application.js:

$(document).on('click', '#go-search', function() {
    findImagesOnGoogle({keywords: $('#search-term').val(), container: '#search-results'})
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#search-results img', function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $("#workspace img").remove();
    var img = $("").attr('src', url);
    $("#workspace").append(img);
    });

The CSS, JS and HTML are all on separate tabs in Sublime Text.

Comment: Posting your HTML will help to debug your problem. Creating a working Plunkr or Fiddle will help much more.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Code can help you. I am not providing you entire solution but making way for you to learn to do code by yourself.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Search Term & Press Enter.." onkeydown="javascript:return checkEnterPressed(event);" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkEnterPressed(thisEvent) {
        if (thisEvent.keyCode == 13) { // 13 : Enter Key
            alert('enter Pressed');
            // Do WHatever you want to do HERE.
            return true; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided you can try something like

```
$('#search-term').on("keypress", function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      findImagesOnGoogle({keywords: $('#search-term').val(), container: '#search-results'})
   }
    });
});
```

and put put this after your last line of code.

An example (not with a search, but with a popup is here) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLangeraert/m9GgA/1/)